# BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am thinking of using BigDecimal to compare two currency values rounded to 2 digits. For example I expect the following to yield 0 because I'm comparing something that should round to 0.02 with something that is 0.02. But it yields -1 !! Is there a right way to do this?

This should also work for larger numbers like 123.45 vs 123.4534 ... which should yield 0 when "compareTo" is used.

I've tried using math context but it doesnt seem elegant ... is there a correct way?

```
BigDecimal spread = new BigDecimal(0.01934);
spread.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.format("0.0193 ? 0.02 = %d\n", spread.compareTo(new BigDecimal(0.02)));
```

AND THE SOLUTION IS:

```
BigDecimal spread = new BigDecimal(0.01934).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
BigDecimal loSpread = new BigDecimal(0.02).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
System.out.format("0.0193 ? 0.02 = %d\n", spread.compareTo(loSpread));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0.02 gets evaluated to

```
java.math.BigDecimal = 0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875
```

You have to setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN) there too.

Comment: That's another way to get an accurate floating point number. 1+.

Comment: Had to use both ideas here to get it right. Will post correct code.

Answer (score 10):

First off, BigDecimal is immutable. You must return the result from your setScale method call:

```
spread = spread.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Next you must improve your accuracy of the second BigDecimal since it is being derived from a double -- not a very accurate entity. So try a String:

```
 spread.compareTo(new BigDecimal("0.02"))
```

Comment: This is actually used to compare prices. They may have to be instantiated from doubles.

Comment: @fodon: Then user unknown has part of your answer for you, and I have the other part (regarding BigDecimal being immutable).

Comment: I reverted the invalid edit. Folks, please _comment_ or provide an _additional answer_ if you aren't satisfied with an answer you see.